# SaveFileDialog. Файл занят

Tags: winforms, .net, c++

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
      SaveFileDialog^ saveFile1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
      saveFile1->Filter = "txt files|*.txt";
      if ( saveFile1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK &&
         saveFile1->FileName->Length > 0 )
      {  
         File::WriteAllText( saveFile1->FileName, nVariable );
      }
                 }
```

Не сохраняет, пишет, что файл, который ты сам же и создаешь, уже занят. Почему?

> The process cannot access the file
> C://test.txt because it is being used
> by another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему я уже решил. Она состояла в том, что при работе ShowDialog файл создавался и открывался, поэтому File:: не имел доступа, нужно было его просто закрыть. Вот код:

```
if (saveFile1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK &&
    saveFile1->FileName->Length > 0)
{  
    saveFile1->Close();
    File::WriteAllText(saveFile1->FileName, nVariable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня Ваш код работает нормально. Попробуйте изменить в системе контроль учетных записей или вырубить антивирус. А лучше попробуйте сохранять файл не на системном диске, например сохраните на диске D:. 
   Я не знаю как кодить на С++.NET, могу предоставить вариант на C#

```
SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
if (s.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
 Stream str = File.OpenWrite(s.FileName);
 StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(str);
 wr.Write("Текст для записи");
 wr.Dispose();
 wr.Close();
}
```

Этот код тоже вполне работает. Попробуйте)